# How to handle multiple related lists of generics in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, type-inference

I have a list of objects typed as GenericType, and T is different for each object.
I also have another list of keys of T (same size as first list).
I would like to map both lists, relate them. I could do it individually but I can't do it when using arrays.
Not sure if it is possible, if it's not I'd like to understand better why this is a limitation, some sources / directions would be appreciated.
We can consider `GenericType<T> = T` to make it simple. This is the example in codesandbox : [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ymg7dp)

If I use a function like this:

```
const func = <T,>({obj, key}: {obj: GenericType<T>, key: keyof T}) => {...}
```

It works as expected if I use an object and key individually, but if I do something like this:

```
const arr = [{ obj: object1, key: key1 }, { obj: object2, key: key2 }] as const;
// works
func(arr[0])
// works
func(arr[1])
// type error
func(arr[Math.round(Math.random())])
```

Comment: You need to include the definition of `GenericType` in your question. You should also include the error message you are getting.

Comment: @NamanNehra I thought it wouldn't be important, I just added an example that has error and a codesandbox link.